# The argument type 'Stream<List<ObjectModel>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<ObjectModel>'

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, bloc, rxdart

I am using BLoC pattern (with rxdart package) to read a list of "EmpresaDatosModel" and when trying to include the sink it throws me the following error:

> The argument type 'Stream <List < EmpresaDatosModel >>' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'List < EmpresaDatosModel >'.

In the BLoC pattern I am using the following code:

```
class EmpresaDatosBloc {

  final _empresaDatosController = new BehaviorSubject<List<EmpresaDatosModel>>();
  Stream <List<EmpresaDatosModel>>  get empresaDatosStream   => _empresaDatosController.stream;

  Stream<List<EmpresaDatosModel>> cargarEmpresasStream() {
    final empresasList = _empresaDatosProvider.cargarEmpresasStream();

    _empresaDatosController.sink.add(empresasList); //THE ERROR THROWS HERE

    return empresasList;
  }
  dispose() {
    _empresaDatosController?.close();
  }
}
```

The provider where the query is made from Firebase RTDB has the following:

```
  Stream<List<EmpresaDatosModel>> cargarEmpresasStream() {
    
    Query resp = db.child('admon');
    final empStream = resp.onValue;

    final publicarStream = empStream.map((event) {
      final empMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
      final empList = empMap.entries.map((e) {
        return EmpresaDatosModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(e.value));
      }).toList();
      return empList;
    });
    return publicarStream;
  }
```

And the display widget looks like this:

```
    final empresaDatosBloc = Provider.empresaDatosBloc(context);
    empresaDatosBloc.cargarEmpresasStream();
    //---
    return StreamBuilder(
         stream: empresaDatosBloc.empresaDatosStream, 
         builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
                  final empresasList = [];
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final myList = snapshot.data as List<EmpresaDatosModel>;

                    myList.forEach((element) {
                      empresasList.add(element);
                    });
                  }
```

How can I assign a `List<EmpresaDatosModel>` to the sink in order to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [.addStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Subject/addStream.html) on the `_empresaDatosController` `BehaviorSubject` .

This forwards data and error events to the controller's stream.

```dart
    _empresaDatosController.addStream(empresasList);
```

Comment: Thank you @victoreronmosele. It works fine. However when I switch to another screen and go back I get an error: `Bad state: You cannot add items while items are being added from addStream`. Ho can I fix it?

Comment: Are you disposing the bloc in the dispose method of the widget where you have the `StreamBuilder` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm using `dispose(){_empresaDatosController?.close();}`

Comment: To be clear, I'm using dispose in the BLoC. Where I have the `Streambuilder` is a StatelessWidget

Comment: I converted SatelessWidget to StatefulWidget in order to do a dispose of empresaDatosBloc where StreamBuilder is working, but the same error appears: `Bad state: You cannot add items while items are being added from addStream`

Answer (score 1):

Hope can help you.
Just keep a reference to `StreamSubscription` and use `Stream.listen()` method

```dart
class EmpresaDatosBloc {
  StreamSubscription<void>? _subscription;

  final _empresaDatosController = new BehaviorSubject<List<EmpresaDatosModel>>();
  Stream <List<EmpresaDatosModel>>  get empresaDatosStream   => _empresaDatosController.stream;

  void cargarEmpresasStream() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _subscription = _empresaDatosProvider.cargarEmpresasStream()
      .listen(_empresaDatosController.add, onError: _empresaDatosController.addError);
  }
  dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _empresaDatosController?.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: It works perfect!! Do you recommend Stateful or Stateless in the widget with Streambuilder?

Comment: IMO, it should be Stateless

Comment: Why? It's not convenient a dispose function?

Comment: @DavidL use Stateful to contain and dispose bloc (is is required) (such as a Screen/Page), otherwise use Stateless as much as posible